# How could I find the GET arguments in BlazeMeter?

Tags: parameters, jmeter, get, arguments, blazemeter

How could I find the GET arguments in BlazeMeter?

E.g. if I am load testing the endpoint `https://my.endpoint.com?foo=${__UUID}` in BlazeMeter I can see only the `https://my.endpoint.com`. While, I would be curious to know the request processing time for each `foo`'s value.

Is it possible to somehow find the GET parameters?

I tried to find out the answer in the [documentation](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us), but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can amend your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration as follows:

1. As the samper "Name" use [`__groovy()` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) to generate a random UUID and save it into `UUID` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(UUID.randomUUID().toString(),UUID)}
   ```
2. And in the sampler "Parameters" use `${UUID}` JMeter Variable reference for the value created in the step 1

[image]

This way each Sample Result will have its own unique label in the [Request Stats Report](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13261982515985-Request-Stats-Report)

[image]